# How to make one partition of a multiple partition USB flash drive bootable?

Tags: boot, usb, partitioning

I have a USB flash drive and I created two partitions on it and I wanted to make one partition of it bootable.

I tried using Rufus and burned an iso file on it but it made the whole USB flash drive bootable. Which is not what I want.

I wanted just one partition bootable not the whole USB flash drive. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You want to make just one partition on your USB flash drive bootable, right?

No worries, I got you covered! Rufus is pretty cool for creating bootable USB drives, but it tends to make the entire thing bootable by default.

To get what you want, you can use a different approach.

**Meet "Easy2Boot"**: A nifty tool that lets you have one bootable partition while keeping the rest for regular stuff.
First, grab Easy2Boot from its website and run it. Plug in your USB flash drive (remember, it'll wipe everything, so back up!).

In Easy2Boot, choose your USB flash drive, pick the "NTFS" file system for the whole thing, and then copy the ISO file you want to make bootable into the main folder. You can still use the other partition for your files, no problem.

Now, when you boot from the USB flash drive, it'll only load the bootable partition, leaving the rest untouched. Easy peasy!
Keep in mind, though, that not all ISO files may work with this method, but for most bootable ISOs, it should be a breeze.

Give it a shot!

Comment: At the moment it looks like spam to me. Would you please make a declaration if you are associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

With Rufus you will need to use GParted later to shrink the partition with OS and create second partition (and format it). Seems like you will be not able to make the second partition with OS (only first).

Only partitions can be made bootable (active). So never the whole drive is active.

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few steps to make only one partition on a USB flash drive bootable using Rufus:

1. Insert the USB flash drive and open Disk Management (press Windows Key + R and type 'diskmgmt.msc').
2. Delete all existing partitions on the USB drive until you only have unallocated space.
3. Create two new partitions on the USB drive - one FAT32 partition for data and an NTFS partition for the bootable OS.
4. Right click on the NTFS partition and select 'Mark Partition as Active'. This marks it as bootable
5. Open Rufus and select the ISO you want to burn. Under 'Partition scheme and target system type', select 'MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI'.
6. IMPORTANT - Under 'Boot selection' choose 'Bootable ISO' instead of 'Disk or ISO image'.
7. Start the burn process. Rufus will now only make the NTFS partition bootable and leave the FAT32 partition untouched.
   This way you can have a USB drive with two partitions - one bootable and one non-bootable for data storage.

Comment: I'm the developer of Rufus and I can tell you that what you describe will not work. Rufus always deletes **all** the partitions before it writes data to the selected disk. Especially, there is no scenario where Rufus will leave an existing partition untouched. See also [this relevant answer from the Rufus FAQ](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#user-content-Why_does_Rufus_need_to_delete_all_partitionsvolumes_when_creating_a_drive).